# C#: Global Hotkey blocks Input

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook, keyboard-hook, global-hotkey

Hello StackOverflow Community.
I wanted to use Hotkeys in my Program so I looked how to make Global Hotkeys.
The Normal Global Hotkeys you find on the Internet are getting blocked by Games or similair programs so I used this one: [CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

The Only Problem now is that all registered Hotkeys are not usable anymore. Even if you write a Text File, you won't be able to use the Keys that are used as a Hotkey.

Thank you.

Comment: Describe what you mean by "Global Hotkeys." Also, did you read the part in the article that says if you hook one of the keys, it prevents any other application from getting that key?

Comment: No I didnt see that. Do you know any other way to make Hotkeys that are still usable by other applications? @JimMischel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found out how it works. If I am not putting e.Handled to the Keyboard Methods, it won't block my Input.
Thank you very much :)